# Redshift connection unit testing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, amazon-redshift

I am new to Python unit testing and I am not sure how i can create a unit test of this function that returns a connection make sure that it always returns something?

Comment: Could you please show the code you want to unit-test?

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing any SQL connection, you can use the command `SELECT 1` which will always return **1** if the command executed successfully. You can specify more columns, column names, and types by just specifying the values in the query.

Example: `SELECT 1 as NUMBER, 'hello world' as TEXT`